# Meaning of a 'singlet' in the context of $Su(n)$?

Tags: terminology, lie-algebras

I am confused about the meaning of the term 'singlet' in the context of the Lie algebras of $Su(n)$ e.g. the singlet within $2\otimes 5\otimes 10$. What does this mean? (Any sources would be helpful).

Comment: This is about irreducible representations of $SU(n)$, see for example [these notes](http://physik.uni-graz.at/~gxe/2013-hadron-physics/hadron-app-3.pdf); page $8$, where for dimension $1$ there is "a single row", or "single column" of the Young diagram.

Comment: The singlet is the representation with dimension 1.